# (iOS) Capture event from non-ascii keys

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic3

I am trying to subscribe to the physical keyboard events (non-ASCII keys) in my app written with Ionic Framework *(issue occurs when I am trying to reach page launched by `ionic serve`, deploying app on my ios device or run it in ios emulator from xcode)*.

```
<div tabindex="1" (keyup)="onKey($event)" (keydown)="onKey($event)" (keypress)="onKey($event)"></div>
```

In the `onKey` function I'm just printing on screen info about which key was hit:

```
onKeyDown(event: any): void {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event.key));
}
```

This function works as expected, until I will hit one of non-ascii keys:

- <kbd>command</kbd>,
- <kbd>control</kbd>,
- <kbd>option</kbd>,
- <kbd>arrow_up</kbd>,
- <kbd>arrow_down</kbd>,
- <kbd>arrow_left</kbd>,
- <kbd>arrow_right</kbd>,
- <kbd>caps lock</kbd>,
- <kbd>shift</kbd>

They are just not logged. I don't get any error message, nothing. When running `ionic serve` in the regular browser, everything works.

What should be mentioned. Those keys works correctly (ie I can navigate within textarea with arrow keys).

I tried also plain JavaScript:

```
  document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
      alert(evt.keyCode);
  };
```

Same result - works with arrow keys on desktop, not works on iPad.

As another try, I used [angular hotkeys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-hotkeys), but this library doesn't work on the ios device.

Comment: I don't have problem with capturing key press. I have problem with capturing non-ascii keys.

Comment: Something else you can try, with plain Javascript: `myTextArea.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => { ... }, true)`. The last boolean is to catch the event in the [capture phase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), in case it would make a difference (Angular catches the events in the bubbling phase).

Comment: Also.. Nothing :/

Answer (score 0):

Try `keydown` event. Unlike the `keypress` event, the keydown event is fired for keys that produce a character value and for keys that do not produce a character value.

Comment: I just tried all three: keyup, keydown and keypress - same result.

Comment: for `tab` and some other buttons is triggered. but if the keyboard button doesn't change the text there is no event to catch this except `keypdown` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown

Comment: Thank you for the link. As I wrote. When I run app on my iPad I don't receive those events (for non-ascii keys). They works only on my computers browser. Maybe there is some different way to catch those? I tried angular-hot-keys but they don't work completely - even for ascii keys

Comment: ok cool didn't see the edit that you did - maybe jquery can help :)

Comment: I just tried plain JavaScript (updated question). It doesn't work either, so I don't think that jQuery would help ;)